# Compilation failure: "cannot find symbol" when applying module-info.java in multi module Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, java-module

**Please disregard this question. For unknown reasons, the project started working when I took a second look at it. After reading [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) in the Stack Overflow question I opt to Close it (instead of Deleting it).**

---

How can I get test dependencies to work in a multi module maven project when using Java 9 modules?

Given that I have the following project structure:

```sh
+ pom.xml
|
+ first
|  + pom.xml
|  + src/main/java/
|               + module-info.java
|               + com/example/first/First.java
|
+ second
|  + pom.xml
|  + src/main/java/
|               + module-info.java
|               + com/example/second/Second.java
|  + src/test/java/
|               + com/example/second/SecondTest.java
```

### First module

The `module-info.java` file in the `first` project looks like this:

```java
module com.example.first {
    exports com.example.first;
}
```

and the corresponding `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<artifactId>first</artifactId>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
```

### Second module

I would like that the `second` module should have a test dependency on the `first` module. For this reason I have attempted the following configuration.

`module-info.java` file in the `second` project:

```java
module com.example.second {
    exports com.example.second;
}
```

`pom.xml` file:

```xml
<artifactId>second</artifactId>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>first</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <scope>test</test>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And the `SecondTest.java` file includes `First` as a dependency:

```java
package com.example.second;

import com.example.first.First;

public class SecondTest {
    First first;
    Second second;

    // setup and test methods...
}
```

### Problem

With the configuration above, the test compilation fails:

```sh
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project second: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] [...]/src/com/example/SecondTest.java: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class First
[ERROR]   location: package com.example.first
```

### Workaround

I could change the scope of the `com.example.first` in the `pom.xml` file of the to `compile` and add `requires com.example.first` in the `module-info.java` file in the `second` module and the test compilation would work. However, that would also imply that the `second` module would depend on `first` when it is being used elsewhere and that is not desired.

Comment: @xerx593 Sorry, my mistake. The `second` module should have a test dependency on the `first` module, see corrections above.

Comment: As it is merely a test dependency, did you add a second `module-info.java` under `src/test/java/`?

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```java
module com.example.second {
   requires com.example.first;
}
```

... (*additionally*) in second/**`src/test/java`**!

Whereas in second/`src/main/java`, we can keep it as:

```java
module com.example.second {
    exports com.example.second;
}
```

as in (second) pom (only):

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>first</artifactId>
  <scope>test</test>
</dependency>
```

**For modules to work we need `maven-compiler-plugin` >= 3.6!**